# Adding audio stream to video stream in C#

Tags: c#, audio, video-streaming, audio-streaming, naudio

I'm designing a video/audio conferencing system using TCP in C#. Here is my video sending function:

```
    void SendVideoBuffer(object bufferIn)
    {
        try
        {
           TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(PeerIP_TXT.Text, 6000);

           NetworkStream ns = tcp.GetStream();
            Image buffer = (Image)bufferIn;
            buffer.Save(ns, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            waveOut.Play();
            ns.Close();
            tcp.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Is it possible to send audio stream on the same port (6000)? If so what function needs to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do can be achieved by the **Expression Encoder SDK**
With this SDK you can combine video + audio and also send them directly over network by using the **Live Broadcasting** topics within the SDK.